# Update column of the dataframe based on another using an list

Tags: python, pandas

I'm learning how to use Pandas DataFrames and I don't know if I'm solving this problem in the best way.

I have a dataframe like this:

| Alias | Identifier | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| dpxcp | 0001 | NaN |
| defpo | 0002 | NaN |

I am wanting to update the values based on the identifier using an list with this two information.

My list (identifier, value): `datas = [('0001', 121), ('0002', 17673)]`

I can do this using a loop.

```
for data in datas:
    df.loc[(df.identifier == data[0]), 'value'] = data[1]
```

But I don't know if that's the best way to do it. I have a feeling that using this way, as the more data I have taken longer will be to update the DataFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with convert list of tuples to `dictionary` for avoid loops:

```
datas = [('0001', 121), ('0002', 17673)]

df['Value'] = df.Identifier.map(dict(datas))
print (df)
   Alias Identifier  Value
0  dpxcp       0001    121
1  defpo       0002  17673
```